# Work on Outlook While Macro is active

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a Macro to run from Outlook which works fine. But I want to be able to create a new email while I have the Outlook Macro is active. The problem is, once the macro form is active, I am unable to click on New Email in outlook. Basically, the Macro is working as a popup and not letting me click on outlook. Is there anyway to overcome this issue. I need the Macro form opened at the same time, I should be able to do anything on outlook too.

Comment: By macro form you mean a userform? Haven't really tried it in OL but try showing your form modeless? e.g. `Userform1.Show vbModeless`.

Comment: Yes I meant the userform (FrmNatEmail). I am not sure under what event you want me to enter this command. I just tried it on Private Sub UserForm_Activate() but it is giving an error.

Comment: In the same event you're calling it. How is it loaded? It should be something like `FrmNatEmail.Show vbModeless`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like FrmNatEmail.Show vbModeless. –  L42

[Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments)